# EF6 Connection takes a long time to fail

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I have some code to connect to a database, pretty standard.

In the DbContext that gets created, I try to query a table.

When I create the DbContext, instead of the actual databases url, i put in some url that doesn't exist.

So I expect failure at this point, the problem is, I can't make it fail any faster than like 30 seconds.

I get a bunch of first change exceptions from `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection`

> > > A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> > >
> > > at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I tried creating a custom `DbConfiguration` and DbExecutionPolicy, but that doesn't seem to get called until after it's tried to connect a whole bunch of times.

```
public class InternalsDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public InternalsDbConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () =>
        {
            var r = new MyExecutionStrategy();
            return r;
        });
    }
}

public class MyExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
{
    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        var s = exception as SqlException;
        if (s == null)
            return false;
        if (s.Number == 53)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I just can't make it fail the connection any faster than like 30 seconds, cause it keeps spinning through some process I can't seem to be able to affect, looks like a retry policy without any back off that fires like 15 times before it gives up and calls into my `MyConnectionStratagy` to figure out what to do.

Any ideas? I'd like it to fail the first time and not keep trying.

Comment: Wow @yoda what does that even mean?

Comment: OMG, indeed it has no sense and it's funny. I wrote my comment at 3:30 am, sorry.

Comment: Haha it's alright, I was reading it and was like "WHAT THE HELL DOES THAT MEAN?!?!?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `Connection Timeout=5;` to the Connection String, if you want to increase for all subsequent commands, use `DbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;`

Comment: But doesn't that affect all commands though? That was my assumption

Comment: You could set it to something else straight after so the other commands work as normal :|

Comment: Right, yeah that's easy enough, but I'm saying that just changing that doesn't make the initial connection fail faster, it still takes just as much time.

Comment: Ok, it's looking like that works. Figures that's why ConnectionTimeout only had a getter in code.